# how to add leaflet.timeline to a layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, timeline, vue-cli-3

I have the same GeoJSON data shown in different layers on my map with a radio button control: points as circleMarker, points as a heatMap and points as a clusterGroup.
I'm trying to add a timeline with these layer control groups.
I have the layergroup working fine and i managed to make the timeline work adding it directly to the map like in the examples:

```
  timelineControl.addTo(map)
  timelineControl.addTimelines(myTimeLine)
  myTimeLine.addTo(map)
```

The problem is when i try to add the timeline to an existing layer so i can toggle using groupedLayer:

```
  timelineControl.addTo(myLayer)
  timelineControl.addTimelines(myTimeLine)
  myTimeLine.addTo(myLayer)
```

The leaflet.timeline library raises 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bottomleft' of undefined

Comment: A `TimeLineSliderControl` is a `L.Control` and can't be added to a `L.Layer`, only directly to a `L.Map`

Comment: thanks @peeebeee ,  with this information i managed to connect my timeline with a layer group by just adding the timeline object to a layer and the TimeLineSliderControl to the map.